# Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 13.*.*.*:3004

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache

I want to run a node server on port 3004 in my ec2 instance which has an IP of 13.*.*.*
when I use the IP address as the host I get the following error

```
    events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 13.*.*.*:3004
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1517:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I also tried using 0.0.0.0 as my host and allowing port 3004 using ufw

```
ufw allow 3004
```

the server does run but when I make the following request using chrome browser

```
13.*.*.*:3004
```

i get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error in browser

I have another node web server running on port 3000 which is working fine
what should i do.
this is my node server code

```
    const http = require('http');


const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3004;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Is that an elastic IP? Or are you just trying to use any random IP?

Comment: it is the dynamic ip assigned by aws.

Comment: Is the other server accessible? Is this EC2 instance public? There’s tons of factors here, what’s the difference between the 2 and go from there